# Alguem consegue identificar o erro nesse código?

Tags: c++, algoritmo

Pessoal me desculpa pelos tipos de perguntas to começando

```c
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  //essa parte até o "for(Nm1==Fim)" o geany encontrou erro
  string  Nm1;
  float PrC=0, PrV=0, Lcr=0, ToC=0, ToV=0;
  int Qt1=0, Qt2=0, Qt3=0;
  for(Nm1== FIM)
  {
      cout<<"Nome da mercadoria: ";
      cin>>Nm1;
      if(Nm1!="FIM")
      {
        cout<<"informe o  preco de compra: ";cin>>PrC;
        cout<<"informe o  preco de v enda: ";cin>>PrV;
        Lcr=100*(PrV-PrC)/PrC;
        if(Lcr<10)
        {
          Qt1++;
        }else{
          if(Lcr>=10 && Lcr <=20)
          {
            Qt2++;
          }
          else
          {
            Qt3++;
          }ToC=Toc+PrC;
          ToV=ToV+PrV;
        }
        Lcr=100*(ToV-ToC)/ToC;

      }
      cout<<"Quantidade de mercadorias com lucro < 10%: "<<Qt1;
      cout<<"Quantidade de mercadorias com lucro < 20%: "<<Qt2;
      cout<<"Quantidade de mercadorias com lucro < 20%: "<<Qt3;
      cout<<"Valor total das compras: "<<ToC;
      cout<<"Valor Total das vendas: "<<ToV;
      cout<<"Lucro total (%) "<<Lcr;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sintaxe errada do comando for. A sintaxe é: for (initialization; condition; increase) statement;. Talvez você estivesse pensando no while e não no for.

Comment: Para utilizar string você precisa de: #include <string>.

Comment: Ok ainda não sei usar  o string, valeu pelas dicas vou aplicar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Os erros que impedem a compilação são:**

- A expressão `for` é utilizada em outro formato, ex. `for(int i, i < 5, i++)`. No caso você deseja utilizar um `while`.
- Na condição do `while`, `FIM` deve estar entre `""` pois é uma string.
- Em `ToC = Toc + PrC`, o segundo `Toc` está escrito com `c` minúsculo. A linguagem C++ diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas.
- Uma vez que você utiliza strings, deve incluir a biblioteca string: `#include <string>`.

**Neste ponto seu código torna-se compilável, mas ainda não funciona. Os erros que impedem o funcionamento são:**

- A condição de parada do `while` deve ser `Nm1 != "FIM"` e não `==`.
- A variável `Lcr` é utilizada para o lucro do produto e para o lucro total, devendo serem criadas duas variáveis separadas.
- Nas cláusulas `if` foram utilizado `<=` e `=>`, mas deveria ser `<` e `>`.
- `ToC` e `Tov` devem ser calculados fora do `else`, direto no aninhamento do `while`.

**Neste ponto seu código funciona, mas há outros aspectos relevantes a serem considerados:**

- A formatação do código é importante, adote um estilo e seja consistente.
- O nome das variáveis deve ajudar a entender o código.
- A formatação da saída de dados deve cuidar de aspectos como espaçamento e quebra de linha (atenção especial ao sumário no fim do loop).

*Implementei uma variante do seu programa com algumas das alterações acima descritas.*

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Nm1;

    float PrC, PrV, ToC, ToV, PrLcr, ToLcr;
    int Qt1, Qt2, Qt3;

    PrC = PrV = ToC = ToV = PrLcr = ToLcr = 0;
    Qt1 = Qt2 = Qt3 = 0;

    cout << "Nome da mercadoria: ";
    cin >> Nm1;

    while (Nm1 != "FIM")
    {
        cout << "Informe o  preco de compra: "; cin >> PrC;
        cout << "Informe o  preco de venda: "; cin >> PrV;

        PrLcr = 100 * (PrV - PrC) / PrC;

        if (PrLcr < 10)
            Qt1++;
        else if (PrLcr < 20)
            Qt2++;
        else
            Qt3++;

        ToC = ToC + PrC;
        ToV = ToV + PrV;
        ToLcr = 100 * (ToV - ToC) / ToC;

        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Quantidade de mercadorias com lucro < 10%: " << Qt1 << "\n";
        cout << "Quantidade de mercadorias com lucro < 20%: " << Qt2 << "\n";
        cout << "Quantidade de mercadorias com lucro < 20%: " << Qt3 << "\n";
        cout << "Valor total das compras: " << ToC << "\n";
        cout << "Valor Total das vendas: " << ToV << "\n";
        cout << "Lucro total (%) " << ToLcr << "\n";

        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Nome da mercadoria: ";
        cin >> Nm1;
    }
}
```